# jquery autocomplete: passing additional parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to pass a couple of additional parameters in my jquery autocomplete URL parameter. I am trying to make a call as follows:

```
$('#subcommodityFrom').autocomplete({

        url: '/ABC/XYZ.action?autocompleteTest=&ids='+ $('#commodityFrom').val() + '&',
        minChars: 0,
        max: 10,
        width: 150,
        scroll: true
    }).focus(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });
```

In the above, 'autocompleteTest' is the server side handler method for the autocomplete call and 'subcommodityFrom' is the id of the text field for which autocomplete is implemented. 'commodityFrom' is another text field which is also populated using an autocomplete call. This value is always empty when checked in server side handler method.

However, if I try to pass a static value like:

`url: '/ABC/XYZ.action?autocomplete=&ids='abc', the correct value can be obtained in the handler method when testing as:

```
String query = getRequest().getParameter("ids");
```

What can be missing here?

Comment: which is the autocomplete plugin used?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.2.6 version. The js files are:  jquery-1.2.6.min.js, ui.autocomplete.min.js, ui.core.min.js. I am using this along with Java stripes framework